# Class based weighted raster aggregation

Tags: r, aggregate, weighted

Let's assume I have a raster representing land use classes in a certain resolution. I have to aggregate this raster with R to a coarser resolution and a modal value approach, in order to have the most dominating cell value in the coarser raster. This is easily achieved with

```
m <- aggregate(r, fact = 3, fun = modal, na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, I would like to weight the different land use classes – e.g. forest class (code 1) has a weight of 4 while water class (code 2) has a weight of 2 and street class has a weight of 1.

Is there a function that iterates through raster cells and applies a weight for each cell?

Thanks for any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reclassify` to applying weights, but then what? Do you still want to compute the modal value after that?

I think what you want is your own function that you provide to aggregate. Perhaps something like this

```
library(raster)
f <- function(x, ...) {
    y <- c(
       rep(x[x==1], 4),
       rep(x[x==2], 2),
       x[x==3]
    )
    modal(y, ...)
}

r <- raster(res=5)
values(r) <- sample(c(1:3,2,3,3), ncell(r), replace=TRUE)

a <- aggregate(r, fact=10, fun=f)
```

Comment: Coo, thanks a lot! This looks very promising, still have to study it a bit more to understand if it fully does what I need.

Comment: Would it also be possible to pass the weights for a varying number of classes from a dataframe with a class column and a weight column?

Comment: For example, if I have this data.frame 
`clutter_class weight clutter_code
1       Forest      1            1
2      suburban_low_building      5            2
3       rural_building      5            3
4       residential_building      5            4`
How could I pass over the codes and the weights?

Comment: I think you should either edit your question or ask a new question