# Pass multiple arguments for custom function to ... in aggregate function in R

Tags: r, function, aggregate, raster

I have a custom function `f` to aggregate a raster with the aggregate function of the raster package. The function should take more than one argument, e.g. the argument `second_argument`.`f` is constructed like this:

```
f <- function(x, ...) {
```

```
aggregate(r, fact=10, fun=f, second_argument = 2)
```

However, this fails when I want to pass the second argument.
What is the correct way of handing additional arguments over from a integrated function (like aggregate())?

EDIT

This is my custom aggregation function:

```
weighted_aggregation <- function(x, ...) {
  y <- c(
    rep(x[x==1], 1),
    rep(x[x==2], 5),
    rep(x[x==3], 5),
    rep(x[x==4], 5),
    rep(x[x==5], 1),
    rep(x[x==6], 1),
    rep(x[x==7], 3),
    rep(x[x==8], 5),
    rep(x[x==9], 5),
    rep(x[x==10], 5),
    rep(x[x==11], 2),
    rep(x[x==12], 3),
    rep(x[x==13], 1),
    rep(x[x==14], 1),
    rep(x[x==15], 1),
    rep(x[x==16], 5),
    rep(x[x==17], 5)
  )
  modal(y, ...)
}
```

This function should apply a weight to each class (classes 1-17) and then calculate an aggregation with the modal function.

The classes and their weights are stored in a data frame:

```
structure(list(clutter_class = c("Forest", "suburban_low_building", 
"rural_building", "residential_building", "Snow", "Water", "Road", 
"dense_urban_high_building", "urban_high_building", "dense_urban_low_building", 
"Railway", "Highway", "Open Urban", "Open Rural", "Rock", "suburban_high_building", 
"urban_low_building"), weight = c("1", "5", "5", "5", "1", "1", 
"3", "5", "5", "5", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "5", "5"), clutter_code = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17")), row.names = c(NA, 17L), class = "data.frame")
```

The aim is to pass the weight and class values of this data frame to the custom aggregation function so that it is flexible (no hard coded weights). Also, the number classes could be varying.

Sample data can be generated like this:

```
r <- raster(res=5)
values(r) <- sample(c(1:17,2,3,3), ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
```

Then I would call the aggregate() function:

```
m <- aggregate(r, fact=20, fun=weighted_aggregation)
```

I don't know how to pass the the weight and class values to the custom function. And it is unclear to me how I can make it flexible to allow a varying number of classes. Somehow the `rep(x[x==1]` part should be created dynamically.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Ok thanks, but I need this for the `raster::aggregate` function, so `dplyr`and `data.table`are not an option. I reckon it should be possible to pass additional arguments somehow?

Comment: Sorry seems like I read your question too fast, you are right ``dplyr`` and ``data.table`` would not be useful for you. Yes I am pretty sure you could pass additional arguments with the ``raster::aggregate`` function since the ``...`` argument is present anyway. What is the error you're having?

Comment: `aggregate(r, fact=10, fun = function(x) f(x, 2))`

Comment: thanks, but this results in `Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (na.rm = na.rm)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that, which is a pity, but then again, you do really need to do that, as you can either write the argument into your function (as a constant) or let the function find it in the global environment.

Here is your function, rewritten for flexibility

```
w_agg <- function(x, na.rm=TRUE, ...) {
    weight <- c(1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5)
    i <- is.na(x)
    if ((!na.rm) | all(i)) {
        return(NA)
    }
    x <- x[!i]
    y <- rep(x, weight[x])
    # to get the same results as with your function you need
    # sort, such that the ties are treated the same way
    # y <- sort(y)
    modal(y)
}

library(raster)
r <- raster(res=5)
values(r) <- sample(17, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
m <- aggregate(r, fact=10, fun=w_agg)
```

Normally, you would make `weight` an argument to `w_agg`, but to use it with different weights in aggregate, you would have to do something like this:

```
w_agg2 <- function(x, na.rm=TRUE, ...) {
    i <- is.na(x)
    if ((!na.rm) | all(i)) {
        return(NA)
    }
    x <- x[!i]
    y <- rep(x, weight[x])
    modal(y)
}

# create another example weights vector 
weight = rev(c(1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5))
m <- aggregate(r, fact=10, fun=w_agg2)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks – it corresponds to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989358/class-based-weighted-raster-aggregation/56991285 I would like to pass the weights via an argument. Ideally, I could pass over a data.frame with combinations of class / weight to the custom function.

Comment: How would I pass the value of argument over from `aggregate()` if I made constant argument in the custom function like this `f(x, y)` ?

Comment: Please edit your question. Add some example data, and add an example of a working function that you would like to use.

Comment: Ok Robert I edited the question, I hope this helps. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Great – except why is it `rev()` on the weight vector? I can reproduce the results when I don't reverse the weight vector.

Comment: I used `rev` to create another weights vector --- just for the example